# Compiler Issues : iostream not working

Tags: c++, std

When i compile my c++ code using g++ 5.1.1 it says

> "narc05b.cpp: In function ‘`int main()`’:
>
> anarc05b.cpp:5:3: error:  ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
> cout<<"hello\n";    ^  anarc05b.cpp:5:3: note: suggested alternative:
> In file included from anarc05b.cpp:1:0:
> /usr/include/c++/5.1.1/iostream:61:18: note:   ‘std::cout’    extern
> ostream cout;  /// Linked to standard output    "

...what does it mean ?

Comment: Isn't it the classic case of missing "using namespace std;"?

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan: Your edit just made the compiler messages harder to read. Do you really think it was an improvement?

Comment: The compiler tells you: `cout` not found. Suggested alternative `std::cout`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace, I do. Sorry. I hope it's not critical.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan - no, it's the classic case of not using a namespace prefix; the correct name is `std::cout`. `using namespace std;` is an abomination. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker, yes. I just proposed the easiest solution for a beginner in C++.

Comment: @ArthurGevorkyan - teaching beginners things that they'll have to unlearn later is not the easiest solution. If someone applied to me for a job and their sample code was littered with 'using namespace std;` it would be a serious detriment to their chances of getting hired.

Comment: @PeteBecker, whatever you say. However, I don't see any potential performance issues and/or name collisions caused in a project that utilizes only one library. For more details, there is Sam Varshavchik's comment below. I don't code in C++ for my living, thus don't want to start a discussion about the pros and cons of those 2 approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use the namespace directive in the code

```
using namespace std;
```

or alternatively prefix cout with `std::cout`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @SamVarshavchik was the question about the merit and demerits of using namespace directive ?  I guess the Answer seeker is new to the coding in c++ env and the answer completely solves his query .... and yes I do agree using namespace has it demerits

Comment: Yes, `using namespace std;` had its demerits. It's a bad habit to get into, and should **not** be recommended to beginners, since they'll just have to unlearn it later.